# What are the allowable extra query parameters for AcquireTokenAsync

Tags: azure-active-directory, exchangewebservices, access-token, adal, ews-managed-api

What are the extra query parameters allowed in the **extraQueryParameters** parameter of [AcquireTokenAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_AuthenticationContext_AcquireTokenAsync_System_String_System_String_System_Uri_Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_IPlatformParameters_Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_UserIdentifier_System_String_)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is for retrieving an authorization code, which as far as I know corresponds to [this authorization flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code), and the query parameters for it are documented there.

You can see how ADAL parses and uses the query parameters from the [source on GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/ADAL-v4.5.1/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/Internal/Flows/AcquireTokenInteractiveHandler.cs#L232-L288). If you attempt to override a query parameter that's already specified by the library (like `redirectUri`) then it will throw an exception.

One example of a query parameter that you may be able to successfully override is `domain_hint`

> Provides a hint about the tenant or domain that the user should use to sign in. The value of the domain_hint is a registered domain for the tenant. If the tenant is federated to an on-premises directory, AAD redirects to the specified tenant federation server.

Most of the other query parameters appear to already be in use by the library, and are either hard-coded by the library or are user specifiable elsewhere.

There's also some documentation for this parameter on [the ADAL wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-interactively---Public-client-application-flows#overrides-of-acquiretokenasync)

> - `extraQueryParameters` (optional) enables application developers to provide extra parameters to the STS endpoints. This can be hints, or a kind of extension point for parameters not exposed directly through the API. This is a comma separated string of keys/values separated themselves by an ampersand: `"key1=value1&key2=value2"`.
> - Note that ADAL.NET also checks if a specific environment variable exists (`ExtraQueryParameter`) and if it does it adds additional query parameter to each query to the STS endpoint.

Which might indicate that this is more useful when using a custom STS instead of AAD directly

Comment: Thank you.  The documentation on Microsoft's page (see Link I provided) is criminally sparse on the subject.